# javascript different behaviour in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Below is my Grease monkey script/Tamper monkey to click on the buttons(multiple buttons), which has the name containing 'attach'. The script is working perfect, however there is a difference in Chrome and firefox.

In Firefox the click happens from top to bottom order of the 'attach'(name containing) buttons.
In Chrome it clicks from bottom to the top, for each page load.

1. Why is this different behaviour
2. Should I be using '===' instead of '=='?

Below is my greasemonkey/tampermonkey script

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
myname = inputs[x].getAttribute('name');
if (myname.indexOf('attach') == 0) {
document.getElementsByName(myname) [0].click();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix little errors here and there - because one browser might auto-correct a syntax error while the others won't (which is often the case for me I've noticed)

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

// Add var to keep scope in the for loop
for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {

    // Add var here or else it will be global
    var myname = inputs[x].getAttribute('name');

    if (myname.indexOf('attach') == 0) {

        // Syntax error: remove ' ' after (myname)
        document.getElementsByName(myname)[0].click();
    }
}
```